# How to validate if the Sanctum token i valid or not in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-sanctum

I want to create an api to check if the token is expired or wrong on laravel 9 but when the token is wrong the postman gave me a response with html page and ignoring my middleware that validates the response .

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide anything specific, I only can recommend you to look at official documentation for Laravel Sanctum especially [this](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#protecting-routes) chapter. There you can get this piece of information:

> To protect routes so that all incoming requests must be authenticated, you should attach the `sanctum` authentication guard to your protected routes within your `routes/web.php` and `routes/api.php` route files. This guard will ensure that incoming requests are authenticated as either stateful, cookie authenticated requests or contain a valid API token header if the request is from a third party.

Make sure that you use `sanctum` guard with your routes, it should look like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/profile', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```